# Angular set Global variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to set my Global variable to a different value based on a string when I open my application.

**globals.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  env: string;
  constructor() {}
  setEnv(setEnv: string) {
    this.env = setEnv;
  }
}
```

**cti-nav.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ListService} from '../../assets/list/list.service';
import {Globals} from '../globals';

export class CtiNavComponent implements OnInit {
    tools = this._ListService.getList(this.globals.env);  //<= returns undefined
    ngOnInit() {
        this.globals.setEnv('int');
        console.log(this.globals.env);  //<= returns int
    }
    constructor(private _ListService: ListService, private globals: Globals) {}
}
```

**cti-nav.module.ts**

```
import {Globals} from '../globals';

@NgModule({
    providers: [Globals]
})
export class CtiNavModule {}
```

**list.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ListService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getList(env) {
    return this.http.get('https://list.url.com/' + env);
  }
}
```

When I check the log it outputs int correctly and then in the _ListService part, it returns undefined. Correct would be if _ListService also returns int.

Comment: Now I don't understand what *returns* `undefined` exactly. The call to `_ListService.getList()`, or is it `_ListService` that is undefined (thus throwing an error at runtime, not returning anything) ?

Comment: @Pac0 added list.service.ts

Comment: GET https://list.url.com/undefined 404 (Not Found) <= Error message

Comment: Thank you, much clearer now. Indeed Mohan's answer's right, it was a problem of order of operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ngOnInit will get called after the constructor and the properties like tools are initialized.  You will have to rework the logic to initialize tools after initializing the Globals.  May be you can try by calling setEnv in the constructor instead of ngOnInit

Comment: Good to know it worked for you!  Can you accept this as an answer?

Comment: I did, had to wait 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Trty to move your   `this._ListService.getList(this.globals.env);`  into constructor or `ngOnInit`

```
  import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {ListService} from '../../assets/list/list.service';
    import {Globals} from '../globals';

        export class CtiNavComponent implements OnInit {
            tools; 
            ngOnInit() {
                this.globals.setEnv('int');
                console.log(this.globals.env);  //<= returns int
            }
            constructor(private _ListService: ListService, private globals: Globals) {
            this._ListService.getList(this.globals.env);  //try to move here
        }
        }
```

Comment: The constructor is called before `ngOnInit` I believe, so this would produce the same result. I think `getList` should be called inside `ngOnInit` after the `setEnv` call.

Comment: try to move it to ngOnInit and say me what you get

Comment: @AntonSkybun had to move getList into ngOnInit, but it didn't work without MOHAN's solution. Thanks!